# Generic backup script

Tags: shell-script, backup

I need to write a backup script for a database running on Ubuntu. I'd like this to preserve the previous days backup, but also several previous backups ideally in a logarithmic fashion. These backups should be stored in folders with the date as name, e.g. 20191016. Previous backups should be deleted to free space. If logarithmic is not possible then at the least backups from the previous N days should be kept. I would like to schedule the backup task using cron.

Is there any existing generic script or executable that can help me achieve this?

I don't think it's particularly relevant, but the database being backed up is Mongo and I plan to perform the backup using mongodump, which can write the dump to stdout or to a specific file or directory.

Comment: Take a look at `rsnapshot` I think that would do what you are looking for.

Comment: @XTian Thanks but I don't think that will work. rsnapshot appears to be for backing up files, but that's risky with a database as we don't know what's in memory and what has been flushed to disk. I need a backup tool which works by invoking another task (i.e. mongodump) rather than just copying files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You back up the database with `mongodump` and then back up the dumpfile with `rsnapshot`, this can be scripted within rsnapshot's configuration file.

The Arch wiki has a good summary of [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rsnapshot#Extra_Scripts).

Here is an extract from `rsnapshot.conf`

```
...
# LOCALHOST
backup  /home/      localhost/
backup  /etc/       localhost/
backup  /usr/local/ localhost/
#backup /var/log/rsnapshot      localhost/
#backup /etc/passwd localhost/
#backup /home/foo/My Documents/     localhost/
#backup /foo/bar/   localhost/  one_fs=1,rsync_short_args=-urltvpog
#backup_script  /usr/local/bin/backup_pgsql.sh  localhost/postgres/
# You must set linux_lvm_* parameters below before using lvm snapshots
#backup lvm://vg0/xen-home/ lvm-vg0/xen-home/

# EXAMPLE.COM
#backup_exec    /bin/date "+ backup of example.com started at %c"
#backup root@example.com:/home/ example.com/    +rsync_long_args=--bwlimit=16,exclude=core
#backup root@example.com:/etc/  example.com/    exclude=mtab,exclude=core
#backup_exec    ssh root@example.com "mysqldump -A > /var/db/dump/mysql.sql"
#backup root@example.com:/var/db/dump/  example.com/
#backup_exec    /bin/date "+ backup of example.com ended at %c"
```

The commented out lines with `backup_exec` or `backup_script` show calling out to a executable or script to perform the dump.